# Confusion with File instance function in Java: How to import an arbitrary .csv file into mysql instead of a specific one?

Tags: java, mysql, csv, intellij-idea, jdbc

I currently already have a code that imports specific .csv files(directory provided) into mysql.

I'm trying to tweak it and play around with the create File() method demonstrated in the java tutorials ie. `File file = new File("d:\\myproject\\java\\Hello.java");` And modified the code as follows:

My code is as shown:

```
import java.sql.Connection;

import java.sql.Statement;
import java.io.*;

public class ImportCsv {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ImportCsv.readCsvUsingLoad();
    }

    public static void readCsvUsingLoad() {

        try (Connection connection = DBConnection.getConnection()) {

            File file = new File("C:/Users/User/Desktop/Test/upload2.csv");

            String loadQuery = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" + "file" + "' INTO TABLE txn_tbl FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','"
                    + " LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'  " + "IGNORE 1 LINES(txn_amount, card_number, terminal_id)";
            System.out.println(loadQuery);
            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
            stmt.execute(loadQuery);
            System.out.println("Data import success");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

However, Intellij keeps throwing back the FileNotFoundException.

Am i misunderstanding the usage of file instance creation here?

Comment: This is correct because you use the file name as a String `"file"` instead you have to remove the two quotes :

    `String loadQuery = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" + file + "' INTO TABLE txn_tbl FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','"
            //-----------------------------^^
            + " LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'  " + "IGNORE 1 LINES(txn_amount, card_number, terminal_id)";`

Comment: Sounds promising! let me give it a shot. So my usage of declaring a file instance was correct after all? EDIT: Tried it, but it still threw the fileexception =/

Comment: Now i'm really confused. When i used "C:/upload.csv" in the File file = new File("") instance it works. BUT if i were to use the FULL address, the program cant find the file!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you use the file name as a String `"file"` instead you have to remove the two quotes, and you don't need to create a file, you just need the `path` (String) :

```
String file = "C:/Users/User/Desktop/Test/upload2.csv";

String loadQuery = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" + file + "' "
        //---------------------------------------^^
        + "INTO TABLE txn_tbl FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' "
        + "LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'  " 
        + "IGNORE 1 LINES(txn_amount, card_number, terminal_id)";
```

---

Another way you can use `getAbsolutePath` like this :

```
File file = new File("C:/Users/User/Desktop/Test/upload2.csv");
String path = file.getAbsolutePath();

String loadQuery = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" + path + "' "
        //---------------------------------------^^
        + "INTO TABLE txn_tbl FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' "
        + "LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'  "
        + "IGNORE 1 LINES(txn_amount, card_number, terminal_id)";
```

Comment: That worked in where i specified the the string name as String file = "C:/upload.csv"  for a file in the same folder as the project. If i typed the full address, it doesnt seem to work =(

Comment: what is your problem no @Mack

Comment: I tried your solution of removing the double quotes. It worked if i typed:  String file = "C:\\upload.csv";                                                                      
If i tried to use the full address like so: String file = "C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\OneNote\\ReadCSVFile\\upload.csv"; The program cant find the file(Filenotfound exception)

Comment: Thanks for the help YCF_L!  It turns out the command that worked for me was: String fileName="C:/Users/User/Documents/OneNote/upload.csv";
         File file = new File(fileName);